# Multiple CREATE INDEX ON in one cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using the browser in 2.0, is there a way to create multiple Cypher queries using CREATE INDEX ON?

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Manufacturer(name)
CREATE INDEX ON :Brand(name)
```

which just returns an un-informative "syntax error" in the browser.

Tried as well:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Manufacturer(name);
CREATE INDEX ON :Brand(name);
```

Even tried ',', the only way this works is by cut/paste each line, appears to be no way to combine them into one script, rather long and pointless as I'm sure there is a way of combining them. No?

Comment: Oh and also tried ```CREATE INDEX ON :Manufacturer(name), :Brand(name)...``` but to no avail.

Comment: Or use the old webadmin, which is available under: http://localhost:7474/webadmin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, you have to do them separately.

*Update as of late 2018*: in one of the recent releases (3.4 or 3.5, I think), they added a new option in the browser to "enable multi-statement query editor", which lets you do multiple statements at once.

Comment: very annoying imho